# convert a letter into binary in c

Tags: c, string, binary

I'm trying to write a code that will get a char and print it in a 12 digit binary.

exapmle :

> str = "a" then the print is : a = 000011000001

My problem is just that I'm trying to work with it as an integer but it won't work.
my code:

```
void addbinary(char str)
{

int binary[12];
int mask = 1;
int i;
int value;
for(i = 11; i >= 0; i--)
  {
      value = str & mask;
      binary[i] = value;
      str <<= 1;
     }
}
```

Comment: Characters are usually 8-bit bytes. Why do you need 12 bits?

Comment: As for your problem, this seems to be the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: The function argument is `char str` so it cannot be given `"a"` it would have to be `'a'`. Do you get compiler warnings? Or, as the name of the argument is `str` did you intend it to be a string?

Comment: Note, it should be `mask <<= 1` and not `str <<= 1`.

Comment: i need to builed a commpiler for assmbly as a project for my class and it needs to work on with an imegenry cpu and we were asked to do it for 12 bits and not 8 like it usualy is

Comment: why cant i do str <<= 1 ? i have a copy of the letter so it doesnt really metter right ? @WeatherVane

Comment: Because the mask always tests bit 0 and after you shift `str` left bit 0 will always be 0. Alternatively you could shift `str` right with `str >>= 1` but beware when shifting signed values.

Comment: Then for unsigned `char` or non-negative values just set the four top bits to zero? And for negative values (if `char` is signed) set the top four to one (sign-extending the value on a two's complement system).

Comment: thanks for explantion! it helped @WeatherVane

Comment: and yes thats what they are looking for in the string part , if your intersted we could talk somewere else and ill explain it completely  @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, please post a [mcve] so we can recreate the problem and help you to debug it.